# time to event for panel data

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a panel data set of country years. I would like to calculate time since event, as well as get a running total of events per country which I can decay over time. I am using the `timeSinceEvent` function in the `doBy` package, which returns a data frame which has the values that I want, but I am having trouble applying this to my main df.

```
structure(list(ccode.a = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L), year = c(1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 
1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 
1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 
2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 
1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 1975, 1976, 1977, 
1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 1975, 1976, 
1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 
1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 1975, 
1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 
1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004), onset.a = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ccode.a", "year", 
"onset.a"), row.names = c(NA, 200L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried using this:

```
last.step <- function(x) {
  temp <- timeSinceEvent(x$onset.a, x$year)
  cbind(x[,1],temp) #timeSinceEvent cuts off the country ID
}
result <- do.call("rbind", by(data, data$ccode.a, last.step))
```

As well as

```
test <- by(data, data$ccode.a, function(x) timeSinceEvent(data$onset.a, data$year))
```

To little avail. I stepped through the function, and it seems to be doing what I want, but I guess there is a problem in the way that I am calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to modify `timeSinceEvent` in the `doBy` package a bit. Here is the final code that worked. Kudos to lselzer for pointing out `rbind.fill` in `plyr` and RoyalTS for pointing out that `timeSinceEvent` returns `null` when the `yvar` argument is all zeros.

```
panel.tse <- function(yvar, tvar = seq_along(yvar)){
   if (!(is.numeric(yvar) | is.logical(yvar))){
        stop("yvar must be either numeric or logical")
    }
   yvar[is.na(yvar)] <- 0
   event.idx <- which(yvar == 1)
   run <- cumsum(yvar)
   un <- unique(run)
   tlist <- list()
   for (i in 1:length(un)){
     v <- un[[i]]
     y <- yvar[run == v]
     t <- tvar[run == v]
     t <- t - t[1]
     tlist[[i]] <- t
   }
   timeAfterEvent <- unlist(tlist)
   timeAfterEvent[run == 0] <- NA
   run[run == 0] <- NA
   ans <- cbind(data.frame(yvar = yvar, tvar = tvar), run, tae = timeAfterEvent)
   return(ans)
 }

last.step <- function(x) {
  temp <- panel.tse(x$onset.a, x$year)
  cbind(x[,1],temp) 
}

result <- do.call(rbind.fill, by(data, data$ccode.a, last.step))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the problem is simply that there are no events for `ccode.a==20` and so `timeSinceEvent` returns `NULL` when applied to that subset. This means that `last.step` returns data frames of different dimension for the two `ccode.a`s and thus the `rbind` fails.

Not exactly a solution, but perhaps better understanding where the problem lies already helps.

Comment: So it is the case that some of the cross sectional units don't have any onsets, but of course many do. I don't understand why the returned df would have different dimensions though. They should match  number of years in the df I pass to `last.step` just have missing values for some of the variables returned by `timeSinceEvent`. Unless I misunderstand..

Comment: It's not the number of rows that's different, it's the number of columns. For the first country in your example `last.step` returns a data frame with 9 columns (because `timeSinceEvent` inside the function returns a data frame with 8 columns) whereas for the second country `last.step` returns a data frame with only 1 column (because `timeSinceEvent` inside the function returns `NULL`). And because the number of columns does not match `rbind` will not work.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense. I was just testing the function on `ID` codes that happened to have at least 1 onset. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are empty columns you should use `rbind.fill()` in `plyr`. It will fill with na the columns that are empty

```
last.step <- function(x) {
  temp <- timeSinceEvent(x$onset.a, x$year)
  cbind(x[,1],temp) #timeSinceEvent cuts off the country ID
}
result <- do.call(rbind.fill, by(data, data$ccode.a, last.step))
```

However this won't return the "empty" `lists` i.e. the one with only the x[,1]. It will only `rbind` those `lists` that have `data.frame` inside. I don't know if this is the expected behaviour and/or is what you want.

Comment: This looks like what I am trying to do, but what is going on with the `if` statement? This is the desired behavior though.

Comment: I'm sorry I was going to add an if but then I thought it wasn't needed but forgot to delete it. Edited

Comment: I got this error `Error in sss[ii, 2]:sss[ii, 3] : NA/NaN argument`

Comment: I also tried it with `if(temp != NULL)` in the line above the `cbind` and got the error `Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`

Comment: @Zach Using the same data you provided?

Comment: Both the data I provided and the main DF.